# VBA Word: can you assign classes, tags, or names to ranges to access them independently of the table format?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a project that has to be done in VBA Word. It has duplicate, dynamically generated tables for different inventory items. Each table has macroButtons that access data within the table to perform certain functions.

The challenge is that the code is extremely layout-dependent. For example, to get the inventory number, I have to reference a specific cell in the table. If the table layout changes, I have to redo a lot of the code. In JavaScript, I would name the inventory number element and access it using something like:

`table.getElementsByName('inventoryNumber')[0].innerHTML`

Is there anything like `getElementsByName`, `getElementsByTag`, or `getElementsByClassName` that I can use to do this in VBA Word? I tried using bookmarks, but I think you cannot use the same bookmark name in duplicate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, a bookmark name must be unique in a document. A possibility would be to use a different suffix in each table. For example, the id of the inventory item. Or keep a running counter, perhaps the same index number as the table in the document.

The other possibility is to use content controls. These may use the same Title and/or Tag property as other content controls in the document.

Individual content controls can therefore not be accessed directly by name, only by the ID number that Word generates for them when they're inserted. Addressing them by name (or tag) can only be done using `Document.SelectContentControlByTitle` or `Document.SelectContentControlByTag`, which returns an collection of all content controls that match the criterium, similar to the JavaScript example you give. In this case, it would be a question of identifying the content control in the table where the MacroButton was clicked. For example:

```
Sub GetCCinSameTable1()
    Dim ccs As Word.Contentcontrols, cc As ContentControl
    Dim cName As String
    Dim tblRange As Word.Range

    Set tblRange = Selection.Tables(1).Range
    cName = "Test"
    Set ccs = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(cName)
    For Each cc In ccs
        If cc.Range.InRange(tblRange) Then
            Debug.Print "Right cc!" & " " & cc.Range.Text
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

An alternate approach would be to get the table where the macro button was clicked and loop all the content controls it contains until the correct one is identified:

```
Sub GetCCinSameTable2()
    Dim ccs As Word.Contentcontrols, cc As ContentControl
    Dim cName As String
    Dim tblRange As Word.Range

    Set tblRange = Selection.Tables(1).Range
    cName = "X"
    Set ccs = tblRange.Contentcontrols
    For Each cc In ccs
        If cc.title = cName Then
            Debug.Print "Right cc!" & " " & cc.Range.Text
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```